# Centering Parts of rich text boxes

Tags: c#, richtextbox, alignment, center, rtf

So I wanna center the selected text in a richtextbox, but when i use this code it centers all the text after aswell.

```
public static void ChangeSelectedTextAlignment(RichTextBox control)
        {
            control.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
}
```

How can I do so it is only the selected text which is centered. Just like word etc

Comment: When do you call this method?

Comment: Why not? I like to have methods to edit so i don't have to edit the place i use it :)

Comment: Haha, yes, I agree with goo coding practice.  My question was "when" not "why"... :)  it also looks like Samresh has the right answer.  I wasn't able to center only a selection of text unless there was a linebreak (new paragraph).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alignment property doesn't work selection wise. It works paragraph wise, where the cursor appears in case a paragraph is not already selected.

Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.selectionalignment.aspx

Comment: So I can't make parts of the text within a rich text box centered